How do I make a WPF DataGridColumn a bound, editable ComboBox where changes to the items are propagated to other rows?
I'm using a WPF DataGrid bound to a collection. One of the columns will be a ComboBox. I want the ComboBox to be editable, and also any changes to the text to be propagated to all other items in the collection that were previously using the same value.
Here is my XAML:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Team Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=TeamNames}" Text="{Binding TeamName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>

and here is my code:
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string teamName;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TeamName
    {
        get { return teamName; }
        set
        {
            teamName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TeamName"));
        }
    }

    public Student(string name, string teamName)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Student>(new Student[] { new Student("Alice", "Red"), new Student("Bob", "Blue"), new Student("Craig", "Blue") });
    public List<string> TeamNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Colors.AddRange(Students.Select(x => x.TeamName).Distinct());
    }
}

So for example, if Craig's team name is changed to "BlueGreen", Bob's should update simultaneously:

I got pretty close by handling the ComboBox.TextBoxBase.TextChanged event, but it was getting complicated enough to make me think there must be a more straightforward way.

I don't quite understand, why changing Craig favorite color from "blue" to "bluegreen" should affect Bob's favorite color? Because you changed color at lets say index 0 and they both use color at index 0? That doesn't make sense to me. I'd expect all persons to have own favorite color. It looks like XY problem. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

You may need to monitor the property changed on the Colors list and then update your student's favorite colors to match the new value rather than the old value. I don't think this is as simple as a binding unless you re-structure your students FavoriteColor to be more like a FavoriteColorId that won't change when the color name changes

@Sinatr I changed it from 'favorite color' to 'team name'. There you can understand a change to one would affect all others on that team, right? But still distinct from actually switching teams.

Ok, let's think about "favorite team". So you are renaming team name liked by both persons. Why it should be possible to rename team name in combobox? I'd expect some separate place to manage teams, adding a new or deleting would be a problematic in combobox, don't you think? I'd customize dropdown of combobox to have there editor of teams, rather than making IsEditable combobox, where you able to quickly change team name. Such design is prone to user mistake, accidentally renaming a team is very possible, you need to confirm it or be able to revert, which adds complexity.

string Team is another problem. If Teams would be a separate data structure (table?) referenced by each student and with some sort of id to reference specific team, then changes to team will affect all students automatically.

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it will work and show you generally how you could approach the problem.
First, modify your Student class to use an id for the Team instead of the name, and add a Team class to handle the Team's Id and Name
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public Student(string name, int teamId)
        {
            Name = name;
            TeamId = teamId;
        }

    }

    public class Team
    {
        public Team(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Then you can key off those values in your ComboBox. When the ComboBox loses focus, you can then update your Teams list via the LostFocus event.
XAML
<DataGrid x:Name="DataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Team Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Teams, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                                SelectedValue="{Binding TeamId, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                IsEditable="True"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

Code Behind
    public partial class EditableComboBox : Window
    {
        public ViewModel DataModel { get; set; }
        public EditableComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataModel = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = DataModel;
        }

        private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var record = (e.Source as TextBox)?.DataContext as Student;
            if (record == null) return;
            DataModel.UpdateTeam(record.TeamId, (e.Source as TextBox)?.Text);

            DataTable.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }

ViewModel
    public class ViewModel
    {

        public IReadOnlyList<Team> Teams { get; } = new List<Team>
        {
            new(1, "Blue"),
            new(2, "Red" ),
            new(3, "Green" ),
        };

        public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>
        {
            new("Name 1", 1),
            new("Name 2", 2),
            new("Name 3", 3),
            new("Name 4", 1),
            new("Name 5", 2),
            new("Name 6", 3),
            new("Name 7", 1),
            new("Name 8", 2),
            new("Name 9", 3),
        };

        public void UpdateTeam(int id, string newName)
        {
            var team = Teams.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if (team == null) return;
            team.Name = newName;
        }

    }

Result

Update
However, this can result in issues with updating the correct record when the user changes the selection of the ComboBox, as the OP pointed out in the comments.
A solution to this is to break up the ComboBox from the editing TextBox. This could be done via the control's template, but in this example, I am just using a TextBox next to the ComboBox to achieve the same effect.
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Team Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox x:Name="combo"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Teams, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding TeamId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            SelectedValuePath="Id"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            IsEditable="True"
                            Width="20"
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="text"
                            Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference combo}}"
                            Padding="2"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus"
                            BorderThickness="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is TextBox textBlock) || !(textBlock.DataContext is Student student)) 
        return;

    DataModel.UpdateTeam(student.TeamId, textBlock.Text);

    DataTable.Items.Refresh();
}



Works great except one issue: when you select a different team from the dropdown and lose focus, it changes the current team's name rather than changing the team itself via the TeamId. Adding SelectedValue="{Binding TeamId, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" I think is the best way to fix that (the TeamId change seems to happen before the event is raised).

Good catch @CraigW I updated my answer accordingly.
